# How to fix npm start "cannot determine native SDK version" error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to run my react native code from a github repository on ubuntu by using npm start and expo. When I run npm start I get the follow error:

"Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again."

I have tried the 'yarn add expo' but that doesn't seem to work because I can't get yarn to work and it doesn't recognize 'add'. I haven't found anything on this problem either. Does somebody know what is going on?

Comment: Wow can't believe the solution was so easy and I was looking for so long damn, thanks! If you post your answer I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `npm install expo` instead of `yard add expo`.

**Note:** `yarn` is another package manager just like `npm`. If you have `npm` installed already then you can replace `yarn add` with `npm install` always.

Comment: can you help with this:
Missing package "metro" in the project at C:\Users\amran\Documents\rn-first-app. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.

Comment: As per first line missing package metro. Kindly check in package.json you need to install metro dependency

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to chime in that running `npm install` solved the problem for me. (I figured out that the problem was probably because my dependencies were not properly installed.)

When grabbing the project from a remote repository, it obviously isn't going to grab the node_modules folder (folder with all the project dependencies) because it's in the .gitignore. Why is it in the .gitignore? Because it's too big and can be easily downloaded on a local machine when needed (by running `npm install`).

This `npm install` command installs all dependencies in package.json into a local folder called node_modules, thus ensuring all my dependencies are properly installed. This then allows my project to work.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me, along with some other threads. Stupid npm/expo dependency issues...

Answer (score 4):

#### Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.

> expo init Game-Zone

> > × Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs.

Same trouble here while installing expo init. But I noticed something wrong in javascript dependencies installation, so I checked the package.json : where it had some highlighted issues on dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
```

## Simple answer is :

> > npm install

** It will simply install pending installation or internet interrupted JavaScript dependencies will be checked or re-installed using the package.json file. If package.json is not update, then delete the whole file and restart expo init name-of-file while cross-checking internet connection   **

Answer (score 2):

I updated npm to the latest version ->
`npm install -g npm@latest`

Uninstalled expo -> `npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save`

Deleted the .expo folder, reinstalled expo & this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error, but the problem isn't in expo. You should verify if you have the node-module file if not, you should run:

```
npm install
```

if that don't work you can force it by:

```
npm install --force.
```

Then run:

```
npm install expo
```

If you are using yarn, you can replace npm by yarn.

Answer (score 1):

This might help for some, because I am new to rn expo. And got this error.

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the dependency file is missing... so you can just replace the node_modules folder which is in your Project folder
eg:
expo init <file_name>
here you will get node_modules folder